# Android application stopped unexpectedly.Tried all other answers

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, signal-strength

I am following a tutorial to create an app to measure the GSM signal strength.Ther are no errors in my files. But my application wont run in the device.
I have attached my codes. Could anybody figure out where the mistake is ?

my mainactivty code

```
package com.example.getgsmsignalstrength;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
   TelephonyManager        Tel;
    MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* Update the listener, and start it */
        MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        Tel       = ( TelephonyManager 
 )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }

    /* Called when the application is minimized */
    @Override
   protected void onPause()
    {
      super.onPause();
      Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
   }

    /* Called when the application resumes */
   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      Tel.listen(MyListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
   }

   /* —————————– */
    /* Start the PhoneState listener */
   /* —————————– */
    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {
         super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Firstdroid!!! GSM Cinr = "
            + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    };/* End of private Class */

}/* GetGsmSignalStrength */
```

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.getgsmsignalstrength"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE">

</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".getgsmsignalstrength"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

My main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

MY logcat shows:

```
06-19 12:04:20.843: D/AndroidRuntime(24717): Shutting down VM
06-19 12:04:20.843: W/dalvikvm(24717): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 

exception (group=0x40018578)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.getgsmsignalstrength/com.example.getgsmsignalstrength.getgsmsignalstrength}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.getgsmsignalstrength.getgsmsignalstrength in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.getgsmsignalstrength-2.apk]
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.getgsmsignalstrength.getgsmsignalstrength in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.getgsmsignalstrength-2.apk]
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
06-19 12:04:20.843: E/AndroidRuntime(24717):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this erroer because there is no activity with the name `getgsmsignalstrength` defined in your project. In your manifest change activity name tag to

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.getgsmsignalstrength"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE">

</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

**Change your activity name** in manifest.xml.Your activity name is **MainActivity**,not the one that you have defined in tour **manifest.xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting class not found exception.

Based on what you have provided in the question, you are not writing the proper activity name in the manifest file. Your activity name is **MainActivity**, and you have written **getgsmsignalstrength**. please do the modification as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.getgsmsignalstrength"

...

<application

...

<activity
    <!--android:name=".getgsmsignalstrength"-->
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```